# Bigquery merge row where start date for one row is the end date for another

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In bigquery, I have a customer table with information about how much he spends X amount of money between a start date and end date like this:

| id | start_date | end_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-10 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-15 | 30 |
| 1 | 2022-02-10 | 2022-02-18 | 10 |
| 1 | 2022-02-18 | 2022-02-20 | 30 |
| 1 | 2022-02-20 | 2022-02-25 | 50 |
| 1 | 2022-02-18 | 2022-03-20 | 5000 |
| 2 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-15 | 30 |
| 2 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-27 | 30 |

And I would like to have this:

| id | start_date | end_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-15 | 130 |
| 1 | 2022-02-10 | 2022-02-25 | 90 |
| 1 | 2022-02-18 | 2022-03-20 | 5000 |
| 2 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-27 | 60 |

The catch is that there can be multiple contiguous rows for the same id, and if there is a merge we want to merge the row with the smallest time interval possible, in the example the row with `id=1,start_date=2022-02-18,end_date=2022-03-20` is not merged.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, min(start_date) start_date, max(end_date) end_date, sum(amount) amount
from (
  select *, countif(ifnull(new_group, true)) over (partition by id order by end_date) grp
  from (
    select *, start_date != lag(end_date) over(partition by id order by end_date) new_group
    from your_table
  )
)
group by id, grp
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]